# Is there a way to perform a time-consuming exit process in MAUI without freezing?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I am looking for a way to handle termination in MAUI and
I have learned that I can write the termination process in the Destroying event
I found out that I can write the exit processing in the Destroying event written in the
[App lifecycle - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle).
However, if I write a time-consuming exit process like the code below, the application freezes just before exiting.

To run a time-consuming process in a separate thread
await Task.Delay(5000);, the application process would be terminated before the task was finished, so
The termination process could not be completed.

How can I run a time-consuming exit process in MAUI without freezing?

Target platforms are expected to be Windows and Android.

Thanks.

### App.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState? activationState)
    {
        var window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
        window.Destroying += (s, e) => 
        {
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); // Long time end process.
            Debug.WriteLine("Time-consuming termination process is completed");
        };

        return window;
    }
}
```

### development environment

- Visual Studio2022
- Windows11

Comment: You probably shouldn't be running time consuming processes on exit.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I asked the question because I was wondering where to write the Close process for Sqlite-net-pcl.

Comment: I would be very surprised if that was a "time consuming" operation

Comment: However, if the Close process is not time-consuming under any circumstances, it seems unnatural that the CloseAsync method, an asynchronous function, is provided.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "async" does not automatically imply "time consuming"

Comment: The bot suggests modifying the question, but the essence of this question is not whether it is a SQLite Close process, but whether it is a 
I am not going to modify the question because I am looking for an effective way to close a time-consuming closing process in general.

Comment: Dear Jason
I just made a manipulation error and deleted my comment right after your reply, so I am posting it again.

I would like to deviate from your question. I understand that asynchronous processing is a mechanism for executing time-consuming processes in a separate thread from the main thread so as not to freeze the main thread, but what other use is there for this?

Comment: On Android, there is **no guarantee** that `OnDestroy` gets called. Therefore, Maui `Destroying` is not guaranteed, AFAIK. I recommend begin in `OnStop`. (Background thread is fine; no freeze.) This will happen whenever app is sent to background. If your Save operation really takes 5 seconds, you need to redesign your app. Have a quick way to save in device storage any updates that have not yet been sent to server. Next time app runs, read back those unfinished updates, and send them to server.

Comment: Dear ToolmakerSteve

This is the first time I have learned that the OnDestroy method may not be executed on Android.
Thank you for the useful information you have provided.

I will try to find the documentation for android applications, as I seem to lack knowledge about android.

Comment: If you want to execute some important actions before exiting your app, I suggest that you can add some menu to do this or detect the back event in the root page, and once the back event is detected, pop up a prompt dialog and then perform the function you need in it.